# Change svg text's vertical position using svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg

I have read the documentation but have no clue how to achieve that. There is no change in `dy`.

```
/**
 * Draws text
 * 
 * @param {String} $text        Text
 * @param {int} $x              Starting point X coordinate
 * @param {int} $y              Starting point Y coordinate
 * @param {Object} $font        Font properties
 * @returns {text}              SVG JS text object
 */
drawText = function($text, $x, $y, $font) {
    $svgText = $svg.text(($text !== undefined && $text !== null) ? $text : '-').attr({x: $x, y: $y}).font($font);
    return $svgText.tspan.dy('0.9em');
};
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies here:

```
return $svgText.tspan.dy('0.9em');
```

On a text element `tspan` is a method, not a reference:
http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#text/tspan

UPDATE:

The `tspan()` method does not return a tspan already present in the text element, it creates a new one. What you are looking for is the `lines` reference. Lines holds all the tspans inside the text element. Because `lines` is an instance of `SVG.Set`, you can call the `dy` method directly on it:

```
text.lines.dy(0.9)
```

If you want to change the `dy` of the first element you can use the `each` method:

```
text.lines.each(function(i) {
  if (i == 0)
    this.dy(0.9)
})
```

Note that the `leading` method might be useful here too:
http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#text/leading

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had the same thoughts. But how can I edit tspan's vertical position? `$svgText.tspan().dy('0.9em');` is not working as well.